# knockout, bootstrap-multiselect, AMD design

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm following Steve Sanderson's example in Architecting Large SPA's in knockout js.  I want to create a bootstrap-multiselect widget in my template.  I've included `"bootstrap-multiselect": "src/bower_modules/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect",` in `require.config.js`.

bootstrap-multiselect is knockout aware - it has the knockout binding handlers already baked in:

```
!function($) {

"use strict";// jshint ;_;

if (typeof ko !== 'undefined' && ko.bindingHandlers && !ko.bindingHandlers.multiselect) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.multiselect = {

        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
       ///etc...
```

If I copy and paste that whole `init:` and `update:` functions into my component js I can get the widget to render and behave appropriately.  But I shouldn't need to do that.  How do I include the bootstrap-multiselect bindinghandlers inside my AMD module?  Simply making sure that bootstrap-multiselect is included in require doesn't work because the binding isn't respected.  Seems like I should be able to do something like

```
define(['knockout', 'bootstrap-multiselect', 'text!./scheduler-profile.html'], function(ko, multiselect, templateMarkup) { 


    ko.bindingHandlers.multiselect = {
        multiselect();
    }
```

but that doesn't work.  How do I include a binding handler defined in a different file in my AMD module that has my viewmodel?

Comment: You should not call a function directly in an object. An object must have properties .i.e it should have key, value pairs.

Comment: ko.bindingHandlers.multiselect = {
        init: multiselect(), update: someFun()
    }